# Android studio auto formatting annotations

Tags: android, android-studio, formatting

How can I set auto formatting like this:

```
    @Mock MyInterface myInterface;

    //  instead

    @Mock
    MyInterface myInterface;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple, go to... (*Jetbrains IDE's like a Webstorm, Android studio, pycharm, etc*)

File -> Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces -> Method annotations and set to ***Do not wrap*** and also Field Annotations .

Note: Changing the setting will not actually reformat all existing ones. It just won't be wrapped when inserted automatically by the IDE, as you want in your question. This applies to all annotations for methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just press enter. It is as easy as that. Write the annotation and press enter.

For new fields writing everything on the same line automatically drops it down (so it goes over two lines). (I'm using the default settings on that so if you have changed anything that isn't what will happen for you).

That assumes the annotation is first (lombok annotations used for the example. Use a different annotation or get lombok to test this case):

```
@Data
public class SomeClass
```

and not:

```
public @Data class SomeClass
```

Writing:

```
 @Data public class testClass{
```

and pressing enter after adding the clamp automatically formatted it. If it doesn't just get the cursor after the annotation and press enter. Force the formatting if it for whatever reason doesn't cooperate.

you can't use the auto-indent shortcut (for me CTRL+I) doesn't add a new line for the annotation and declaration because both are valid ways to write it and both are "prefered". Writing it on the same line is just the same as writing it on its own line. Auto-indent doesn't correct it